# [WSO2 ESB][4.9.0] NPE on iterate when sending back

Tags: nullpointerexception, iterator, wso2, wso2-esb

Newbie on WSO2 ESB, we start using it as our central point as ESB but we are facing a real issue by doing a simple case :/

Here is the api I wrote ([based on that simple](http://www.vitharana.org/2015/03/aggregate-two-rest-responses.html)) to show you my issue even if our usecase is different.

1. Users

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<api context="/services/users" name="ListUsersAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" url-mapping="/*">
    <inSequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{ "persons":{ "person":[ { "Id":"1", "givenName":"ajith", "lastName":"vitharana", "age":"25", "contactInfos":[ { "InfoId":"1", "department":"1", "contactType":"email", "value":"ajith@abc.org" }, { "InfoId":"2", "department":"1", "contactType":"mobile",
          "value":"111111111" }, { "InfoId":"3", "department":"1", "contactType":"home", "value":"Magic Dr,USA" } ] }, { "Id":"2", "givenName":"shammi", "lastName":"jagasingha", "age":"30", "contactInfos":[ { "InfoId":"1", "department":"1", "contactType":"email",
          "value":"shammi@abc.org" }, { "InfoId":"2", "department":"1", "contactType":"mobile", "value":"2222222222" }, { "InfoId":"3", "department":"1", "contactType":"home", "value":"Magic Dr,USA" } ] } ] }}</format>
        <args/>
      </payloadFactory>
      <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" />
      <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json" />
      <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </resource>
</api>
```

2. Roles

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<api context="/services/roles" name="UserRolesAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" uri-template="/{personid}">
    <inSequence>
      <filter regex="1" source="get-property('uri.var.personid')">
        <then>
          <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{ "Id":1, "roles":[ { "roleId":1, "personKey":1, "role":"Deverloper" }, { "roleId":2, "personKey":1, "role":"Engineer" } ]}</format>
            <args/>
          </payloadFactory>
          <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" />
          <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json" />
          <respond/>
        </then>
        <else/>
      </filter>
      <filter regex="2" source="get-property('uri.var.personid')">
        <then>
          <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"personId": 2,"roles": [{ "personRoleId": 1, "personKey": 2, "role": "Manager" },{ "personRoleId": 2, "personKey": 2, "role": "QA" }]}</format>
            <args/>
          </payloadFactory>
          <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" />
          <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json" />
          <respond/>
        </then>
        <else/>
      </filter>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </resource>
</api>
```

3. Finally, the main one, calling the first one, then iterating

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<api context="/userdetails" name="UserDetailsAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="GET" protocol="http">
    <inSequence>
      <call>
        <endpoint>
          <http method="get" trace="disable" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/users" />
        </endpoint>
      </call>
      <iterate attachPath="//jsonObject/persons" expression="//jsonObject/persons/person" id="it1" preservePayload="true" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <target>
          <sequence>
            <property expression="$body/jsonObject/persons/person/Id" name="uri.var.Id" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" />
            <property expression="$body//jsonObject//person" name="response1" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" />
            <call>
              <endpoint>
                <http method="get" trace="disable" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/roles/{uri.var.Id}" />
              </endpoint>
            </call>
            <loopback/>
          </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
      <sequence key="fault" />
    </faultSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

Executing the last api (http://localhost:8280/userdetails) is causing the following NPE:

```
20160408T101619.566 org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:609) [PassThroughMessageProcessor-14] PassThroughHttpSender - Failed to submit the response
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LoopBackMediator.mediate(LoopBackMediator.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:241)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:679)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:244)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20160408T101619.576 org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:246) [PassThroughMessageProcessor-14]     Axis2Sender - Accept:*/*,Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch,Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,Cache-Control:no-cache,Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8,Host:localhost:8280,Postman-Token:3bfb96b7-0c31-964e-8c37-3b5dbd222efe,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><Id>1</Id><roles><roleId>1</roleId><personKey>1</personKey><role>Deverloper</role></roles><roles><roleId>2</roleId><personKey>1</personKey><role>Engineer</role></roles></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LoopBackMediator.mediate(LoopBackMediator.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:241)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:679)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:244)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    ... 26 more
```

I'm afraid, this is the same issue than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203258/wso2-esb-4-9-send-mediator-causing-errors?newreg=5dd0ac4e227946248e630b7d62168d20) (but not sure).
**Would you please help me** quickly to avoid before we decide to give wso2 away ?
The better would be to have the third part (userdetails) fixed by an answer.

Thank a lot !

Comment: Benjamin, I'm trying to understand the third part - you have an iterate mediator which does a call and then does a loopback and triggers the <send> back in the outSequence. In this scenario, do you only want to iterate and call http://localhost:8280/services/roles/{uri.var.Id} endpoint as an "out only" invocation and you do not want to aggregate all the responses before responding back to the client with <send> back?

Comment: In my final goal, I want to filter on the inner call (roles) to call another "out only" call to insert data with a third party service. But here, it was a sample simplified to show NPE. I really don't mind what is sent back to client. Did you succeed in make it work (with or without added aggregate) or do you have NPE ?

Comment: Let me go through your configs and get back to you.

Comment: Just saw your updated comment. In that case, the issue you're facing is you're trying to do multiple responses to the client. Each time you iterate, you do a loopback causing the outSequence to trigger - this makes your first response go back to client and then the ESB will try to send more responses on each consecutive iterate. Since HTTP is a request/response cycle, you can only send one response back to client. If you care about the response in such a case, you should use the aggregate mediator. Since in this case you don't, please move your loopback call out of the iterate mediator.

Comment: Benjamin, please see my answer.

Comment: Ok. So it means that to fix it, just put the "loopback" after the iterate? Or remove it? Cause, I've just tried it and i've got the same issue :(

Comment: You can place the loopback after the iterate. Removing it will stop the mediation flow inside the inSequence of the API. Please see my answer and let me know if that fixes. I was unable to reproduce with that.

Comment: Apologies, looks as though you're correct. Let me look into this again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your loopback is inside the iterate mediator and that is calling outSequence each time you iterate.

<s>If you move your loopback mediator out of the iterate as shown below, this should send the last response from the iterate to the client. If you want to aggregate your responses from the iteration, you should use aggregate mediator[1]</s>. 

    
       
          
             
                
                   
                
             
             
                
                   
                      
                      
                      
                         
                            
                         
                      
                   
                
             
             
          
          
             
          
          
             
          
       
    

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Aggregate+Mediator

**Updated**

Unfortunately the above solution does not work, because each time an iteration completes, the flow still continues, so even if we have a loopback outside the iterate, we will be calling the outSequence multiple times. We will have to use an aggregate to be able to use the complete condition to trigger the outSequence once. Please have a look at the below configuration.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="UserDetailsAPI" context="/userdetails">
   <resource methods="GET">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http trace="disable" method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/users"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <iterate xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" id="it1" preservePayload="true" attachPath="//jsonObject/persons" expression="//jsonObject/persons/person">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="uri.var.Id" expression="$body/jsonObject/persons/person/Id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="response1" expression="$body//jsonObject//person" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                  <call>
                     <endpoint>
                        <http trace="disable" method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/roles/{uri.var.Id}"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </call>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
         <aggregate id="it1">
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="//jsonObject">
               <loopback/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <sequence key="fault"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code (and seen the place for loopack) but I've got same issue: [2016-04-08 11:34:05,716] ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender Failed to submit the response
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)

Comment: Perfect. So definitely, aggregate does the job !! Thanks for quick and efficient answer. Appreciate a lot !!!